# Adding snyk as a post-install step?

Tags: package.json, post-install, snyk

The [snyk wizard documentation](https://snyk.io/docs/cli-wizard/) recommends adding `snyk protect` to your project as a **post-install** step. How exactly do you do that? I referred to the entire **package.json** documentation [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#keywords) and couldn't find any reference to a *post-install* keyword.

Answer (score 3):

There's some small difference between `snyk wizard` and `snyk protect`. Adding `snyk protect` is indeed a good practice, as it applies any potential patches to make your node app more secure. The `snyk wizard` will guide you through also upgrading the versions of your dependencies if they solve any vulnerabilities.

More info on [snyk protect](https://snyk.io/docs/cli-protect/). When using the Fix PR functionality for a npm project, it will be automatically part of the PR, if it involves any patches.

An example can also be found [here](https://github.com/joris-snyk/goof/blob/673fb16e2fc531e19edd4c2727e47fcfbf6b3d07/package.json#L14), Line14-21